# Comparing string numbers in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a usage case like;

```
val fieldType = "int" // we know what is the type of field
val value1 = "1" // can be double/int/long/float etc.
val value2 = "2" // can be double/int/long/float etc.

val operator = "=" // can be >, >=, <, <= etc.

def compare(operator, value1, value2): Boolean = {}
```

Couldn't find a good way to do this. Is there any way to do this efficiently?

**EDIT**

I've just made this one but not sure this is the most efficient way;

```
  private def apply(fieldType: String, operator: String, value1: String, value2: String): Boolean =
    operator match {
      case ">" =>
        compare(fieldType, value1, value2) > 0
      case ">=" =>
        compare(fieldType, value1, value2) >= 0
      case "<" =>
        compare(fieldType, value1, value2) < 0
      case "<=" =>
        compare(fieldType, value1, value2) <= 0
      case "==" =>
        compare(fieldType, value1, value2) == 0
    }

  private def compare(fieldType: String, value1: String, value2: String): Int =
    fieldType match {
      case "string"     => value1.compareTo(value2)
      case "int"        => value1.toInt.compareTo(value2.toInt)
      case "long"       => value1.toLong.compareTo(value2.toLong)
      case "float"      => value1.toFloat.compareTo(value2.toFloat)
     
    }
```

Comment: Convert the numbers to doubles using `toDoubleOption` and use pattern matching on the operator.

Comment: I'm assuming you are interested in relational operators. "=" is the assignment operator. Perhaps you meant the "==" operator ?

Comment: yes @AlinGabrielArhip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage of this solution is that it's generic, so it will work for all numeric types.

I'm using the implicit ordering that Scala provides for every numeric type. And I provide a generic compare method that works for very numeric type. But I still had to parse `fieldType` to figure out what types I should compare.

`T : Ordering` means a *context bound* - this avoids the explicit use of an implicit parameter in the method, and lets Scala provide one of type `Ordering[T]` automatically wherever I need it in the body of the method.

`implicitly[Ordering[T]` is a standard library method that tells Scala to look for an implicit definition of type `Ordering[T]`, call it, and return the object right back, then use the methods defined in trait `Ordering` for comparation purposes.

These 2 ideas fuse together to eliminate the need to include an implicit parameter for the method, because we are not interested in an explicit ordering parameter:

```
  def compareBy(fieldType: String)(
      op: String,
      a: String,
      b: String
  ): Boolean = {
    def compare[T: Ordering](op: String, a: T, b: T): Boolean =
      op match {
        case "==" => implicitly[Ordering[T]].eq(a, b)
        case "<"  => implicitly[Ordering[T]].lt(a, b)
        case "<=" => implicitly[Ordering[T]].lteq(a, b)
        case ">"  => implicitly[Ordering[T]].gt(a, b)
        case ">=" => implicitly[Ordering[T]].gteq(a, b)
        case _    => throw new UnsupportedOperationException("op not supported!")
      }

    fieldType match {
      case "byte"   => compare(op, a.toByte, b.toByte)
      case "short"  => compare(op, a.toShort, b.toShort)
      case "int"    => compare(op, a.toInt, b.toInt)
      case "long"   => compare(op, a.toLong, b.toLong)
      case "float"  => compare(op, a.toFloat, b.toFloat)
      case "double" => compare(op, a.toDouble, b.toDouble)
      case _ =>
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("fieldType not supported!")
    }
  }

  val a = "10"
  val b = "2"
  val op = ">"
  val intFieldType = "int"
  val compareInts = compareBy(intFieldType) _

  println(compareInts(op, a, b))     // true
```

The solution seems over-engineered. The following observations can lead to a more compact one:

- we can treat any number as a `Double`, because no precision is lost from converting the smaller type `Float` to `Double` or from converting integral types to `Double`.
- in the corner-case where we want to compare 2 numbers given as floating-point string literals using an integral type, we drop the precision using `longValue`, then convert them back to `Double`, to remove the need of a generic method. By using `toDoubleOption` first, we also remove the `NumberFormatException` when parsing a floating-point string literal as an integral type.

  ```
  def compareBy(
      fieldType: String
  )(op: String, a: String, b: String): Boolean = {
    def compare(op: String, a: Double, b: Double): Boolean = {
      op match {
        case "==" => a == b
        case "<"  => a < b
        case "<=" => a <= b
        case ">"  => a > b
        case ">=" => a >= b
        case _    => throw new UnsupportedOperationException("op not supported!")
      }
    }

    val x: Double = a.toDoubleOption.getOrElse(
      throw new NumberFormatException(s"given $a is not parsable as $fieldType")
    )
    val y: Double = b.toDoubleOption.getOrElse(
      throw new NumberFormatException(s"given $b is not parsable as $fieldType")
    )

    fieldType match {
      case "byte" | "short" | "int" | "long" =>
        compare(op, x.longValue.toDouble, y.longValue.toDouble)
      case "float" | "double" => compare(op, x, y)
      case _ =>
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("fieldType not supported!")
    }
  }

  val a = "10.1"
  val b = "10.2"
  val op = "=="
  val intFieldType = "int"
  val compareInts = compareBy(intFieldType) _  

  println(compareInts(op, a, b))    // true
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I was also working on a solution as well. I've edited the question and added the solution I've just made. But I don't know which one is more type safe and performant.

Comment: Either is fine. Type-safety is implied by the type checker. Performance is the same, as the methods I am calling are doing the same checks as you are doing in the `apply` method.  However, you might need to pay attention to `NumberFormatException` . For example,  say you want to compare 2 ints but you provide 2 double. "10.46".toInt will throw a `NumberFormatException`. And I would recommend default cases in case you misspell the `operator` or the `typeField` strings. Using `toDoubleOption` as Luis recommended is a good idea.

Comment: yeah there is always a change to get `NumberFormatException`. Converting long value to double is a good idea? Or you meant that i should use toLongOption, toDoubleOption etc. for each case?

Comment: btw, if you meant that you should add double case for compare method, i'm gonna add all possible values. it was just a demo.

Comment: The latter, yes, I would use `toLongOption`, `toDoubleOption`, etc. for each case. Converting a long value string to a double will also throw a `NumberFormatException`, because it is not parsable as a Double. When the number is of type `Long`, converting it to `Double` works, but not when the Long number is a String. You first have to parse it as a `Long`, then convert it to a `Double`, to avoid that exception.

Comment: Thank you much, I'm thankful! Marked your comment as correct answer, if anyone comes here it can apply any solution it want.

Comment: If the result is always a boolean there is no need for so much over-engineering, just call `toDoubleOption` directly, it is even safer than the current approach.

Comment: Ah, I see your point now, indeed I agree. I thought that `Long` string literals such as "10L" are not parsable with `toDoubleOption` , but it turns out that they are not parsable whatsoever, not even with `toLongOption` , so you would just have to ensure that the long string literals do not contain `L` , and you can parse all types as Long. Thank you Luis!

Comment: But I still see the issue of comparing floating point string literals as Integral numbers. For example, comparing "10.1" with "10.2" using `==` as Ints or Longs should result in `true`, but using `toDoubleOption` will results in `false`.

Comment: Reedited my anwer based on Luis's obervations.